# How to create a fast custom pixel format

Tags: c#, performance, image-processing, pixel, system.drawing

Due to the requirements of what I am trying to do, I need to have my own custom class for pixels. For each pixel I have:

```
byte red
byte green
byte blue
int brightness
int X
int Y
```

I need the coordinates, so I can make arrays, that consist only of the pixels that I need to draw. For example, if I have a line, that moves diagonally, I only want to have a one-dimensional array of the pixels, that I need to draw; I don't want to have to scan through the rest of the pixels, so I can avoid needless scanning. In my current case, I will have a lot of polygons, which must be applied on an image in a specific sequence and in specific ways. This will be for a game engine, so I have to try to avoid scanning through pixels, which won't be used anyway.

However, having the data in the Pixel class like that, it makes things slow. Really slow. Maybe hundreds of times slower than the default pixel format with which Bitmaps get created. Along with that, making changes to the pixels is extremely slow on its own.

How can I speed up the creation and manipulating of pixels, while storing all the information for color, brightness and coordinates in each pixel?
A side question: is there a place where it is explained how the pixel formats in System.Drawing work?

Answer (score 0):

You can overload `[]` to access an internal array of a singleton instead of many class instances accessing in a strided pattern.  So `pixels[n].X` will access "pixels" object's internal array or array of structs, then get the X out of it fast.

Have all pixel attributes in a struct. Use indexing from pixel class to access that struct. Put that struct in a struct array.

Use StructLayoutAttribute to pack struct into a proper size(and alignment) for better access performance.

Reorder the fields in struct to be able to read all data in (probably)less number of memory operations.

Could be useful if you use all attributes in a function.

---

Instead of array of structs, you can use an unmanaged memory area(given by your game engine's allocator) for all pixels and read by bigger chunks to elliminate transition overheads.(can read a whole struct in just 1 or 2 intrinsic load instructions). Update in bigger chunks(or accumulate temporary results in) using pointers and unsafe contexts.

```
int X
int Y
int brightness
byte red
byte green
byte blue
byte alpha
```

should be able to fit in a 16-byte struct boundary.

---

If you are going to use coordinates separately from colors, or some attributes will not be use always, you should detach it and use as an array of primitives so it makes one less stride element to iterate for next pixel. If you are going to use X and Y together in some space search algorithm but not colors, you can have X and Y regrouped in another array(not in class, just) of structs each having X and Y so color attributes don't get in your way performance-wise.

---

When you access X,

```
public class MyPixel{
  public float X{
                get{ /* access an array or 
                        array of structs or 
                        unmanaged memory */} 
                set{ /* same */}
  }

  // for unrolled loops
  public static void BatchUpdateXY(float[] source,int pixelStart,int pixelEnd)
  { /* copy from source */}
}
```

Even if setter getter costs %50 performance so you may try `pixels.X[i]` instead and have max speed(with arrays or unmanaged memory).

---

Adding a new pixel becomes harder with pure C++ arrays in upper solutions so you may need vectors or similar containers in C++ side.

Answer (score 0):

That's actually what drawing functions are doing in an optimized way (and probably hardware accelerated). Not sure why you need your own drawing functions (i.e. calculating each pixel to form a diagonal line or a polygon).

Maybe, instead of calculating and storing each pixel, you could store only the points that need to be connected, and then call a drawing function to do the work?

If you really need to do this yourself, probably the best way would be to create an array or vector of 32 bit RGBA integers of size width * height which would be a lot faster to handle.

And.. that is actually a bitmap, so what you could do is create a bitmap in memory, use standard drawing functions to draw the lines on that bitmap (which is an array with your RGBA points). Going once through all the pixels at the end will be a lot faster than doing this in a 1D array, which would need to be searched, kept sorted, and grown.

You could even use `TransparentBlt()` to move all the 'non-zero' pixels to your image in one go.